# rails paperclip - trouble uploading multiple images to one model through nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, nested-forms

I have been trying to figure out how to upload multiple images to one model through a nested model for a while now with no luck. I have a Project model, and for each project i would like to upload multiple images. I created a model called Picture and nested it within the Project model, and have set up paperclip and everything seems fine except when I upload an image and click on "Create project", the image does not show on the "show" page. There is no error message displayed. Please help as I do not know how to proceed from here.

here is my code:

Project form:

```
<%= bootstrap_nested_form_for @project, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |f| %>

 <% f.fields_for :pictures do |builder| %>
    <% if builder.object.new_record? %>

      <p>
        <%= builder.file_field :image %>
      </p>

    <% end %>
    <%= builder.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
  <% end %>

  <p>
   <%= f.link_to_add "Add Images", :pictures %>
 </p>

 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Project controller:-

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
    respond_with(@projects)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@project)
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
    @project.pictures.build
    respond_with(@project)
  end


  def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project.pictures.build
  end

  def create

    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created project."
    redirect_to @project
    else
    render :action => 'new'
    end

  end

  def update
    @project.update(project_params)
    respond_with(@project)
  end

  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    respond_with(@project)
  end

  private
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:id, :title, :description, :status, :phase, :location, pictures_attributes: [:id, :image])
    end
end
```

Projects model:-

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['picture'].nil? }

end
```

Pictures model:-

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :project
 has_one :image

 has_attached_file :image,
:path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
:url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", 
:styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

 validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

end
```

Show page:-

```
<% @project.pictures do |picture| %>

  <%= image_tag picture.image_url %>
<% end %>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @project.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @project.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Status:</strong>
  <%= @project.status %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Phase:</strong>
  <%= @project.phase %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Location:</strong>
  <%= @project.location %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>
```

schema :-

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150728092717) do

create_table "pictures", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "project_id"
  end

  add_index "pictures", ["project_id"], name: "index_pictures_on_project_id"
create_table "projects", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "status"
    t.string   "phase"
    t.string   "location"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: If the image is created then you are displaying it wrong. This `<%= image_tag picture.image_url %>` should be `<%= image_tag picture.image.url(:medium) %>`

Comment: tried this but still the images are not showing. Any ideas what else might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your form and whitelist uses the property name `image`.

But you are rejecting any nested pictures if they don't have the `picture` param.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['picture'].nil? }
```

Nested attributes params are not wrapped in a "model key" like rails form params usually are. This is what they look like:

```
params = {
  project: {
    pictures_attributes: [
      {
        image: 'foo.jpg'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can catch these kind of errors quite simply with model specs:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Project do
  it 'accepts nested pictures' do
     project = Project.new(pictures_attributes: [{ image: 'foo.jpg' }])
     expect(project.pictures.first).to to_be_a Picture
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think you should be doing `has_one :image` and `has_attached_file :image`. I haven't used paperclip but it does not really make sense at all since paperclip stores on the disk, not in an ActiveRecord model.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to answer. I am still not exactly sure how to go about solving the problem though. I am quite new to rails and coding in general so I dont really know how to use model specs. Where should I implement the params code you mentioned?

Comment: Is there something I should add/change with the create action in my project controller?